# While Dispatching the thunk action, the state updates but the related state in the function which calls the dispatch remains old one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

The following dispatch is supposed to fail. But the redux store will be updated.
the logging inside the handleBtnClick doesnot show the updated value in the scope.

```
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const storeData = useSelector((state) => state.some);

  const { error } = storeData;

  console.warn("Outside", error);

  const handleBtnClick = async () => {
    await dispatch(getWeather());
    // This will display the old stat
    console.warn("inside", error);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (values) => console.warn(values);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("in Render", error)}
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button onClick={handleBtnClick}>Do Api Call</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-bird-q0kbw)

Comment: Why are you awaiting the dispatch for the async call for weather? It's coming in via `state`, just let the component re-render automatically when state updates.

Comment: You are logging error but expect error to be different than when you created the closure. This is called using a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: @HMR This problem also exists when using connect instead of hook.

Comment: @lux, I could do that, but I just wanted to know why it contains old state even after the dispatch is done. I have tried using the connect still displays old state.

Comment: @OxyDev Stale closure from hook or connect is irrelevant, in handleBtnClick the value error is available as closure the dispatch will trigger the reducer to create a new state that maybe has a different state.some.error but that doesn't change `error` in `handleBtnClick` closure, hence it's called a stale closure.

Comment: @HMR, ohh I see. Thanks!!!